# Is it ok to use an array of objects in Rest Controller

Tags: spring, rest, controller

I'm writing a controller that handles an array of object, something like:

```
@PostMapping("/post")
public void saveEmployeeArray(@RequestBody Emoloyee[] employeeArray)   
{
  // Method body
}
```

Keep in mind that, in this case, employees are usually created, update, or deleted in bulk, meaning, I usually need to handle multiple employees at the same time.

A colleague told me that although it works I should only handle one employee in the controller as, according to him, it's rest best practice. But he didn't present an alternative to the issue of having to handle multiple employees most of the time, other than making multiple requests.

My question is, how is the best way to handle multiple objects?

Answer (score 0):

If your list of Employee is inside another data structure (e.g. company), you can offer PATCH operation for outer resource to add or change a list of Employees. JSON PATCH is specified in RFC 6902, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902/

The JSON body of a PATCH request would look like this:

```
[
  { "op": "add", "path": "/employees", "value": { "name": "Employee 1", ...} },
  { "op": "add", "path": "/employees", "value": { "name": "Employee 2", ...} },
  ...
]
```

The body is a list of PATCH operations to change the addressed data structure at several places within one request, so it fits to your requirement.

The specification in RFC 6902 offers more than just adding elements, you can also remove, replace, move, copy and test. Have a look in the RFC for good and simple examples.